# How can I prevent the class being added to the header before scroll takes place

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, class, scroll

I am trying to use javascript to add a class to my header when the user scrolls, however the class scrollled2 is being added before the scroll takes place.

The code I am using is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var s = $(".site-header");
    var pos = s.position();                    
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (windowpos >= pos.top & windowpos >=50) {
            s.addClass("scrolled2");
        } else {
            s.removeClass("scrolled2"); 
        }
    });
});
```

I need the effect of the scroll to beging after the first 50px have been scrolled past.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using & (or) && in your "if (windowpos >= pos.top & windowpos >=50)" line??

Comment: ^^^ change `if (windowpos >= pos.top & windowpos >=50) {` to `if (windowpos >= pos.top && windowpos >=50) {`  (`&&`)

Comment: @freedomn-m I should add I am editing an existing site which had been buillt in beaver builder. I changed what you suggested, however now the class isn't being added at all.